# Error libc.so.6 version GLIBC_2.33 not found

Tags: linux, gcc, 32-bit

I'm trying to execute a 32 bits binary, that is my scenario:

Host compiled: Kali (64 bits)

Host executed: Debian 7 (32 bits)

```
Host compiled is the machine where I'm compiled to 32 bits the .c 
Host executed is the machine where I'm executing the 32 bits binary
```

I have the package `gcc-multipart` installed and compiled using this command: `gcc -m32 binary.c -o program -pthread`

File Result:

```
program: ELF 32 bits LSB pie executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

When a try to execute in Debian, this error ocurrs `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.33' not found`

I'm looking for some solutions, try to re-install/upgrade the libc6, but did not work.

Comment: Are the gcc versions of the two systems the same?

Comment: no, the Debian is being the binary already compiled, and does not have gcc, I need it to run it? I already bring the binary compiled.

Comment: Since your library depends on gcc, if dibain does not have gcc, it will raise a error when link gcc's dynamic library

Comment: So, What I need to do for bypassing it?